# MongoDB: $unionWith a single value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections. I need to get the highest value of a field in collection A and find all documents in collection B that don't match that value in one of their fields. I suspect `$unionWith` is my answer, but I can't get it working.

Here are my collections:

```
BulkTests:

{
   _id: 65b82f4b13f7b6653662795d,
   testDateTime: 2024-01-29T23:05:47.940+00:00,
   testId: 19
},
{
   _id:65bac13912032ee4eae1d47f,
   testDateTime:2024-01-31T21:52:57.185+00:00,
   testId:20
}

-------
Testers:

{
    _id: 65bc139856f9734f1d19285d,
    name: "FooBar Bizzle",
    testResponses:[
        7,
        19
    ]
},
{
    _id: 65bc139856f9734f1d19285d,
    name: "Baz Bar",
    testResponses:[
        20
    ]
}
```

And here's my aggregation pipeline:

```
{
    $project: {
      lastTest: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$testResponses",
          {
            $indexOfArray: [
              "$testResponses",
              {
                $max: "$testResponses",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      name: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      lastTest: {
        $ne: 20, // this value should be the highest 'testId' from the first collection!
      },
    },
  }
```

The first stage gives me what I need from the 'Testers' collection:

```
{
   _id: 65bc139856f9734f1d19285d,
   name: "FooBar Bizzle" ,
   lastTest: 19 
}, 
{
   _id: 65bc139856f9734f1d19285d,
   name: "Baz Bar",
   lastTest: 20 
}
```

What I need to do is replace the "20" in the final match stage with the max value of 'testId' in the first collection. I'm fighting `$unionWith` but it won't do what I want. I've tried many things...but here's one example:

```
{   
   coll: 'BulkTests',  
   pipeline: [    
      { $project: { foo: { $max: "$testId"}}},
      {$match:{'foo':'lastTest'}}  
    ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this case, I think the `$facet` stage should meet your requirements.

1. `$facet` - Allow multiple pipelines to be executed within the stage.

   1.1. `$lookup` - Get all documents from the *BulkTests* collection.

   1.1.1. `$project` - Get the max value of `testId`.

   1.2. `$project` - Decorate the output document from the *Testers* collection into the `Testers` array.
2. `$unwind` - Deconstruct the `Testers` array into multiple documents.
3. `$match` - Filter the document with `Testers.testId` is not equal to the first value of `maxValue` from the `BulkTests` array.
4. `$replaceWith` - Replace the input document with the `Testers` document.

```
db.Testers.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      BulkTests: [
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "BulkTests",
            let: {},
            pipeline: [],
            as: "BulkTests"
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            maxValue: {
              $max: "$BulkTests.testId"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      Testers: [
        {
          $project: {
            lastTest: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$testResponses",
                {
                  $indexOfArray: [
                    "$testResponses",
                    {
                      $max: "$testResponses"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            name: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Testers"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          "$Testers.lastTest",
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$BulkTests.maxValue",
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$Testers"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0EkqwEhe4kc)

Comment: `$unwind` and `$group` is not needed. Simply use `{$set: {maxValue: {$max: "$BulkTests.testId"}}}`

Comment: Hi @WernfriedDomscheit, thanks for the suggestion, ya it can be simplified. =)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. I don't have enough reputation to up-vote, but this is what I needed.